# Recursive CTE to uniquely number groups in data set

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, recursion, sqldf

My dataset is as follows:

```
Product_1   Product_2
   A           B
   A           A
   A           C
   C           D
   B           C
   E           E
   Z           Z
```

What the table says is that product A in reality is product B then product A is of course product A, product A is also the same as product C but considering that product C is product D in the end product A is also the same as product D.

I need to add a column to this table that groups all the same products as follows:

```
Product_1   Product_2  Group
   A           B         1
   A           A         1
   A           C         1
   C           D         1
   B           C         1
   E           E         2
   Z           Z         3
```

I'm using R therefore I'm thinking of using a recursive CTE with the package sqldf. 
It's big data so using a matrix to solve the problem would push me over 1.3 TB that I don't have.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relation is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), so `b` computes relationship for both directions to make the following queries simpler.

`closure` is the recursive CTE, and computes the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure), i.e., all possible combinations of equivalent products.

`ec` computes [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class), i.e., for each product, it computes the smallest product name in the same class, e.g.:

```
A|A
B|A
C|A
D|A
E|E
Z|Z
```

`g` computes the group number by counting how many smaller distinct `class` values there are:

```
A|1
B|1
C|1
D|1
E|2
Z|3
```

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE b AS (
  SELECT product_1, product_2 FROM MyTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT product_2, product_1 FROM MyTable
),
closure AS (
  SELECT product_1, product_2 FROM b

  UNION

  SELECT c.product_1, b.product_2
  FROM closure AS c
  JOIN b ON c.product_2 = b.product_1
),
ec(product, class) AS (
  SELECT product_1, MIN(product_2)
  FROM closure
  GROUP BY product_1
),
g(product, g) AS (
  SELECT product,
         (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT class)
          FROM ec AS ec2
          WHERE ec2.class <= ec.class)
  FROM ec
)
UPDATE MyTable
SET "Group" = (SELECT g
               FROM g
               WHERE product = MyTable.Product_1);
```

> It's big data

Then let's hope you have a big disk for temporary data …

Comment: Even trying to run this code with the data mentioned above I get no updates on the original dataset: data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows.                                                                                                             Warning message:
In rsqlite_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
  Don't need to call dbFetch() for statements, only for queries

Comment: The warning is caused by the latest version of RSQLite and can be ignored.  You can avoid it by downgrading to an older version of RSQLite.