# Group rows based on relationship using recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

| Product_1 | Product_2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |
| E | F |
| I | A |
| K | A |
| M | I |
| W | V |

I want to be able to group the products based on their relationship. There's no hierarchy (no parent/child) in the relationship so it can go both directions.

So the expected output is something like:

| Product_1 | Product_2 | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 |
| B | C | 1 |
| E | F | 2 |
| I | A | 1 |
| K | A | 1 |
| M | I | 1 |
| W | V | 3 |

I have tried my solution based on previous answer here: [Recursive CTE to uniquely number groups in data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47030724/recursive-cte-to-uniquely-number-groups-in-data-set)

But for some reason it goes to infinite loop and errored out and with just two rows of data.

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
  Prod1 VARCHAR(1),
  Prod2 VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO Product
VALUES ('A', 'B'),
       ('B', 'C');

with b as
(select prod1, prod2 from product
 union all
 select prod2, prod1 from product
 ),
 closure as
(
select prod1, prod2 from b
union all
select c.prod1, b.prod2 
from closure c
inner join b on c.prod2 = b.prod1
)
select * from closure
```

Any ideas where I went wrong? Also, is it better to explicitly define b or just traverse in both directions within the cte?

Appreciate any tips or hints.

Comment: Why not use a SQL Server GraphDB table?

Comment: Hmm a quick google seems to indicate it's only for SQL Server 2017+. I'm using SQL Server 2014 - sorry should have mentioned that